# unable to view Matlab notebook in Jupyter

Tags: matlab, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run matlab code from Jupyter notebooks.
I am following the link below for guidance:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WufMGW5Bv4g

Now I have installed matlab_kernel. And I see that it is installed on the machine when i run a `pip list`.

When I open Jupyter notebook, and click on the New notebook dropdown, I do not see the MATLAB option.

Also, at point 3:22, the instructor installs python from Program Files/Matlab.
However, I do not see the MATLAB folder in my Program Files.

What am I missing here. Any guidnce would be very helpful.

Comment: Okay, so i installed matlab_kernel in a conda base env, and i see the Matlab option now.. but i am curtious why did it not work when i worked outside a conda env

Comment: now i am unable to execute any matlab code. when i do a `disp("hello world")` and do a Shift+Enter to execute the cell, nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have MATLAB installed?

Comment: @max i only installed matlab-kernel following the instructions in the video; what is the procedure to install matlab pls?

Comment: also don't i need to have a license for matlab?

Comment: No, you need a licensed MATLAB instance. This is also stated in the video (right at minute 0:32 + it is written on the screen). You won't get the MATLAB environment for free. You may want to go ahead and install Octave as the free alternative to MATLAB

Comment: @max I have installed the octave-kernel as well, and in Jupyter notebook I use the octave-kernel; but unable to execute any cell. the Jupyter notebook only says IN[*]

Comment: ah so octave and octave-kernel is different

Comment: yes. The kernel is the link between the environment and Jupyter. So you need to install the environment as well (this is "octave" in your comment)

Comment: Is this question now obsolete since your [more recent question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64762944/unable-to-execute-matlab-code-both-in-jupyter-and-online-compiler)?

Comment: @max so i have installed the environment as well, but still unable to execute it in Jupyter

Comment: Perhaps you can check your PATH. You further want to [check which Python version is supported by your MATLAB version](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/python-support.pdf). There may also be some helpful [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/get-started-with-matlab-engine-for-python.html) on how to use the MATLAB engine in Python (can you do this? So no Jupyter, just `Python import matlab.engine`?